# Got a used Electric oven - not sure what wire and breaker to use

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, oven

We just got a used electric oven.  We had propane, but no longer have access to propane.  Currently there is only a standard wall outlet behind the oven.

I realize I need to run a new wire, etc., but am over my head as far as what type of wire, what type of breaker, etc.

**The metal panel inside the oven door says:**

> 3 wire 120/208 - 240 volts - 60 Hz AC ONLY
>
> KILOWATTS 208 VOLTS
>
> KILOWATTS 240 VOLTS
>
> WHIRLPOOL
>
> MODEL RE374PXDN 0

I have a double-30 breaker open in the box.  Can I use that, or should I get something bigger?

Is the "3 wire 120/208" the description of the wire I need?

I tried looking it up by the model number, but it doesn't appear to exist.  Any help greatly appreciated[image: oven]

Comment: There should be a number in front of each "kilowatts". Can you post a photo of the panel?

Comment: Is it a range (stove top and oven in one free standing unit)?

Comment: Sorry for the quality, but i attached a photo.  I think I translated the details pretty exactly, but.... let me know if you see anything that you need to know that's not legible and i can try for a better photo.

Comment: Model is RF374PXDN0.  Install guide can be found here.  http://www.whirlpool.com/digitalassets/MLPDF/Installation%20Instructions%20-%203189985.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need:

- NEMA 14-50 receptacle.
- 40 ampere double pole breaker
- Four 8 AWG copper conductors, or four 6 AWG aluminum conductors (Hot, Hot, Neutral, Ground).

It's common for builders to use a 50 ampere breaker and larger conductors,  to make sure the circuit can handle any range the owner's might use. But if you're installing the circuit to support a particular device, you may be able to use a smaller circuit.

It's common to use aluminum conductors for range circuits, because it's a bit cheaper when you start using larger conductors. Type SE (service entrance) cables are common for range circuits, as it's often easier to pull a cable than individual conductors.

In layman's terms. Go to the electrical supply shop, or hardware store. Tell them what you're doing, and ask for:

- A four prong range plug.
- A four wire range cord.
- 8/3 with ground NM (nonmetallic) cable (copper).
- A double pole 40 amp breaker.

Comment: I looked up NEMA 14-50 receptacle, but it looks like it has 4 holes - my chord only has 3.  Is that Okay?  We hope to get a new/better electric oven soon-ish, if that makes a difference.   I have no idea what the "Four 8 AWG copper conductors" are - is there a layman term for those - search came up empty.

Comment: I have a length of 10-3 wire long enough to use for this - is that the right kind of wire?

Comment: You're going to have to install a new 4 wire cord on the range, and use the 4 prong receptacle. You'll also need 8/3 with ground copper cable, or four 8 gauge individual copper wires. The 10 on your 10-3 cable, means there are 10 AWG (American Wire Gauge) wires (conductors) in the cable. Which are too small for this application. The 3 on the 10-3 cable, means there are 3 current carrying conductors in the cable.

Comment: You might want to consider having  an Electrician install the circuit for you.

Comment: Thanks, @Tester101.  It's starting to sound like you're right - I should just hire a professional.

Answer (score 2):

The install guide for the oven lists a 40 amp circuit.

Comment: Is that this part you're referring to?:  "A three-wire or four-wire, single-phase, 120/240-volt, 60-Hz, AC-only, electrical supply (or three-wire or
four-wire 120/208-volt if specified on the model/serial rating plate) is required on a separate, 40-ampere circuit, fused on both sides of the line."

Comment: Does that mean a double-40 breaker (in layman's terms?).  Also, what type of wire would I need?  Will the wire actually show "120/240-volt, 60-Hz, AC-only"?  I thought they said things like "13-2" or ... stuff like that.  I assume I'd need 3 wire, since the plug that's on it has 3 prongs, which matches the 3-wire diagram.

Comment: When it comes to circuits beyond normal outlets I'll let others with more experience answer.

Answer (score -2):

just use romex 8/3 with ground or 8/2 that way you'll have your hot nuetral and ground and itll do 40 amps. Grab a 2pole 40 or a "double 40" as you put it